Need to fetch a value from a row based on the exact match of two cells in the same row in MS Excel
I have two spreadsheets in an excel file. One looks like this:

Second one looks like this:

Now, I need to fetch Price in Spreadsheet 1 based on Date and Name from Spreadsheet 2. Please help.
Tried using Vlookup but it is fetching the first match but I need to compare two values in two columns together.

There are many ways. One of them:
=FILTER($C$9:$C$12,($B$9:$B$12=$A3)*($A$9:$A$12=B$1),"")

Drag it right and down.
Result:

If no FILTER function in Excel:
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$9:$C$12,MATCH(TRUE,(($B$9:$B$12=$A3)+($A$9:$A$12=B$1))=2,0)),"")


Don't have Filter and Index Match not working, not sure why found this somewhere else as well but no luck, not sure why.

Why does it mean "not working"? What result do you get?

Since FILTER is not available, I assume you are using an older version of Excel.
Would you try making the price data into a table (named in my example tblPrices) with a helper column as in



Index
Date
Name
Price




=TEXTJOIN("-",,[@Date],[@Name])
29-Apr-2024
Dennis
50


will get filled down automatically
29-Apr-2024
Pablo
40



22-Apr-2024
Pablo
55



22-Apr-2024
Brad
34



Then use VLOOKUP



Date
29-Apr-2024
22-Apr-2024




Name




Dennis
=VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN("-",,B$1,$A3),tblPrices,Price_col_index,FALSE)



Pablo





define Price_col_index=4 and fill the formula.
